# How to generate dynamic title in R markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I know about [this solution](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/dynamic-yaml.html), but it doesn't seem to be working. Essentially I want a title with a date at the end; "report 20120719", "report 20210726" and so forth....

First I tried to specify the title later in the document by referencing a date variable, after I told Rmarkdown to load my global envirnment. Which generated the original title without any modifications whatsoever.

I then tried to enter the date manually into the title, but even that doesn't seem to be working:

```
---
title: "Report `r print("20210719")`"
output: word_document
---
```

I get an uninformative error message claiming that:

```
Error in yaml::yaml.load(..., eval.expr = TRUE) : 
  Parser error: while parsing a block mapping at line 1, column 1 did not find expected key at line 1, column 44
Calls: <Anonymous> ... parse_yaml_front_matter -> yaml_load -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Try adding this :
`date: "Last compiled on \`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')\`"`
to your YAML

Comment: BTW: You get the error because you use double quotes inside a double quoted string. You have to replace one of the pair of double quotes by single quotes.

Comment: @stefan Thanks! But if I replace the inner pair with simple quotes the date string still isn't added to the title?

Comment: ... that's because of the print statement. You could replace it with e.g. `sprintf` or follow the code suggested by @Desmond to add the dates.